# Does changing permissions to a certain role affect other roles?

Tags: sitecore-commerce, powershell-extensions

I have a role, "Role1", - a member of "RoleA". Also, I have created a new role, "Role2", which is also a member of "RoleA".

Now, I want to change the permissions in workflows and templates of Role2. So I run the script that I have created.

**Workflow**

```
$allowWSWrite = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight workflowState:write -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity "Role2"
$allowWSDelete = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight workflowState:delete  -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity "Role2"
$allowWCExecute = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight workflowCommand:execute -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity "Role2"

Get-Item -Path "master:system/Workflows" | Set-ItemAcl -AccessRules  $allowWSWrite, $allowWSDelete, $allowWCExecute
```

**Templates**

```
$allowRead = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:read -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission AllowAccess -Identity "Role2"
$denyDelete = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:delete -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "Role2"
$denyWrite = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:write -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "Role2"
$denyRename = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:rename -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "Role2"
$denyCreate = New-ItemAcl -AccessRight item:create -PropagationType Any -SecurityPermission DenyAccess -Identity "Role2"

Get-Item -Path "master:sitecore/templates" | Set-ItemAcl -AccessRules $allowRead, $denyDelete, $denyWrite, $denyRename, $denyCreate
```

Upon checking, Role1 cannot create/edit a page which it previously could.

Does it has something to do with the permissions I have changed in Role2? Please advise.

Comment: Re *"Role1 cannot create/edit a page which previously can"*: Do you mean *"Role1 cannot create/edit a page which it previously could [create/edit]"* (one word added, *"it"*, and one word changed, to *"could"*)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does.

When you use `Set-ItemAcl` you overwrite all the security settings which were assigned to that previously.

When you set new access rights for `Role2` you removed everything what was set there for `Role` before.

If you want to add some access rights instead of overwriting everything, try using [`Add-ItemAcl`](https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/security/add-itemacl) instead:

```
Get-Item -Path "master:sitecore/templates" | Add-ItemAcl -AccessRules $allowRead, $denyDelete, $denyWrite, $denyRename, $denyCreate
```

Comment: Is there a way to revert the permission of Role1?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is no option to revert what was set there earlier.